# Deutsches Äquivalent zum englischen "a living and breathing thing"?

Tags: phrase-request

Im Englischen existiert die Phrase:

> A *living and breathing* thing

Damit gemeint ist etwas *Lebendiges* im Sinn von *aktiv*, bspw. “a living and breathing document” würde ein Dokument bezeichnen, an dem aktiv gearbeitet wird, während “he created a living and breathing world” sich darauf bezieht, dass, zum Beispiel, ein Autor eine Welt erschaffen hat, welche glaubwürdig und authentisch wirkt.

**Gibt es im Deutschen ein entsprechendes Äquivalent zu dieser Phrase?** (oder zumindest eine Annäherung?)

Comment: den ersten Fall würde ich als "im Fluss" bezeichnen, den zweiten einfach mit "lebendig".

Comment: Ich habe als Beispiel sowohl „lebende Verfassung“ als auch „lebendige Verfassung“ gefunden, weiß aber nicht, ob die Bedeutung die selbe ist. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lebende+Verfassung%2Clebendige+Verfassung&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clebende%20Verfassung%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clebendige%20Verfassung%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mir fällt kein Ausdruck ein, der über „lebendig“ hinausgeht und auf **beide** Beispiele anwendbar ist.

Wenn ich auf das Wort lebendig verzichten möchte, würde ich für dein erstes Beispiel (je nach Kontext) „in fortlaufender Entwicklung“ sagen oder von einer „aktiven Community“ sprechen, falls das Dokument von mehreren Personen bearbeitet wird.

Die erschaffene Welt könnte „voller Lebenskraft“ oder „von eindringlicher Lebensnähe“ sein. Sie könnte den Leser auch „durch ihre Atmosphäre in ihren Bann ziehen“.

Answer (score 0):

Ich denke, am nächste kommt dem "gedeihen(d)". Das passt zwar eher zu 2. Beispiel, trifft meiner Meinung nach aber auch (zumindest teilweise) auf das erste Beispiel zu.

P.S.: Eigentlich meine ich ein anderes Wort mit fast der gleichen Bedeutung wie gedeihen, welches jedoch auch gut auf Dokumente zutrifft. Ich komm nur grad nicht drauf.